# Distinguish between nullable and optional fields in GraphQL partial update

Tags: graphql

As you know some fields may be optional in GraphQL. It means that **the server** can't return `null` for them and if they are in `input` the user can assign `null` to them **or the user can omit this field at all** in his mutation.

And if one wants to create a `partialUpdate` then the troubles begin. It **is technically possible to distinguish between not included field and `null` field** on backend. But the problem is that your schema actually lies about some fields.

Check this out:

```
type Address {
  street: String!
  streetNumber: Int!
  apartmentNumber: Int # Optional as some people live in houses
  city: String!
  postalCode: String!
  country: String!
}

input AddressFullInput {
  street: String!
  streetNumber: Int!
  apartmentNumber: Int
  city: String!
  postalCode: String!
  country: String!
}

input AddressPartialInput { # It's partial update, all fields are optional
  street: String
  streetNumber: Int
  apartmentNumber: Int # This field is optional AND nullable
  city: String
  postalCode: String
  country: String
}
```

In `AddressPartialInput` user may think that he can set `null` to all fields, but he **can not**. He can set `null` only to the `apartmentNumber` field, the rest **can be omitted** but **can't be `null`**.

How to address this issue? It seems to me like the only solution is to tell the client: *Hey, look at the `Address` type so you eventually will know what fields can be actually `null` in the `AddressPartialInput`*.

Comment: Not sure there is a solution to this. Your mutation needs to enforce your optional but not nullable rule. ps. Also recommend a `string` for `apartmentNumber` since letters are common in apartment numbers - e.g. "3A"